# How to compile PHP with OpenSSL on OS X 10.9?

Tags: homebrew, php, openssl

So I'm while trying to compile `PHP` 5.6.10 from the source faced the following problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC", referenced from:
      _zif_openssl_pbkdf2 in openssl.o
  "_TLSv1_1_client_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
  "_TLSv1_1_server_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
  "_TLSv1_2_client_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
  "_TLSv1_2_server_method", referenced from:
      _php_openssl_setup_crypto in xp_ssl.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

The `OpenSSL` is installed via `Brew`. In `PHP included like`--with-openssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2c`

P.S.
Before tried to use just `/usr` for `OpenSSL` but got the same error.

Comment: I have this same issue, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: on OS X using --with-ssl=/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/{version} works on compiling most apps that depend on it. If not, what is the error?